# Замена выделеного текста jquery

Tags: jquery, text

Ave! Как можно заменить выделеный текст с помощю jquery? Припустим у меня есть текст - "Съеш моих мягких булочек да закуси вареничком". Я выделяю слово "мягких" и нажимаю на кнопку [`<b>`]. Выделеное слово вырезается и заносится в ф-цию где к нему добавляются теги и ставляется на место мигающего курсора. В итоге имеем html строку:-"`Съеш моих <b>мягких</b> булочек да закуси вареничком`".

Я не прошу сделать все за меня как в тз. Просто мне нужно указать путь по которому идти
дабы знания сии обрести.

P.S. всем булочек[image: ![dango]

Comment: Я делаю редактор в браузере

Comment: Почему нужно именно через jQuery? Обёртка в тег — достаточно несложная операция. В Sublime Text выделяете нужный текст → `Alt` + `Shift` + `W` → где замигал курсор, вписываете название тега. Тег сам закроется за Вами. [Пример](http://imgur.com/ql4uw2l). Спасибо.

Comment: Я делаю визуальный текстовый редактор. http://www.alltrades.ru/img/news/243.png

Comment: Так ет ни я булочки убрал ето какой-то женоненависник. Ща верну

Comment: Вернул девулю на место)

Comment: Неужели даже искать не пробовали? Вот, [первая попавшаяся ссылка](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6328718/wrapping-a-selected-text-node-with-span) и даже [с примером](http://jsfiddle.net/VRcvn/)

Answer (score 2):

```js
foo=function()
    {       
    var selection= window.getSelection().getRangeAt(0);
    var selectedText = selection.extractContents();
    var span= document.createElement("span");
    span.style.backgroundColor = "yellow";
    span.appendChild(selectedText);
    selection.insertNode(span);
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam rhoncus  gravida magna, quis interdum magna mattis quis. Fusce tempor sagittis  varius. Nunc at augue at erat suscipit bibendum id nec enim. Sed eu odio  quis turpis hendrerit sagittis id sit amet justo. Cras ac urna purus,  non rutrum nunc. Aenean nec vulputate ante. Morbi scelerisque sagittis  hendrerit. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et  malesuada fames ac turpis egestas.</p>
<input type="button" onclick="foo();" value="Выделить"/>
```

Comment: Если помог вам, отметьте как ответ